# laravel artisan commands are not working in dos. it's giving me the errors

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel im am trying to make controller but getting the error.

could not open input file: artisan.

I just install the laravel with the controller.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are in the laravel folder.